# Convert from string column in pandas dataframe to time h:mm:ss

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have a column in my dataframe that has values like this: **00:23:44**
how can i convert it from string to time h:mm:ss ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `errors='coerce'` for convert not datetimelike values to missing values with [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html), but later processing is problematic:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], errors='coerce').dt.time
```

If need processing values later use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'], errors='coerce')
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['00:23:44','00:23:47','###']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], errors='coerce').dt.time
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
        col      time       timedelta
0  00:23:44  00:23:44 0 days 00:23:44
1  00:23:47  00:23:47 0 days 00:23:47
2       ###       NaT             NaT
```

Comment: I got this error
ValueError: Could not convert '###' to NumPy timedelta

Comment: @MostafaWaleed - answer was edited.